# Как задать дочернюю переменную?

Tags: c#, переменные, элементы-управления

Я не так давно начал изучать C#, и пока что, к сожалению, не знаю всех тонкостей и возможностей. Принципиально изучаю методом проб и ошибок, ну и иногда заглядываю в гуглы за поиском ответа. Так вот, перейду к вопросу: можно ли в C# у элементов управления задавать дочерние переменные? Я делаю простой текстовый редактор с вкладками, и мне нужно присвоить к каждому элементу вкладок RichTextBox изменяемый флаг isSaved для манипуляций. Попробую привести пример того, чего я добиваюсь:

```
RichTextBox TE = new RichTextBox()
{
Dock = DockStyle.Fill,
Name = "text_edit",
Location = new Point(3, 3),
Text = content,
Font = Properties.Settings.Default.GlobFont,
Margin = new Padding(3, 3, 3, 3),
/* а вот и то, что мне нужно */
bool isSaved; /* собственное значение */

};
```

Comment: Вам нужно унаследоваться от RichTextBox и создать свой класс, который будет содержать поле bool isSaved

Comment: Вы подходите к задаче неверно. Быть сохранённым или нет — не свойство контрола. У вас должна быть структура данных, описывающая _документ_, и в ней поле `isSaved`, а также содержимое документа (и, возможно, ещё поля).

Comment: UI элемент не должен содержать бизнес логики

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            RichTextBoxMy TE = new RichTextBoxMy();
            TE.isSaved = true;
        }

    }
    public class RichTextBoxMy : RichTextBox
    {
        public bool isSaved;
    }
```

Comment: Да, и по правде подход не верный. То что я делал было просто наброском, так как я адаптировался к синтаксису C# после Lua. Пожалуй, перепишу текстовый редактор снова, уже грамотно обдумав всю организацию программы в плане кода. Спасибо за ответы!